# Borel-Laplace transform

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I have some questions about Borel-Laplace transforms: I can not find any good references explaining in details all what follows:

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n\ge0}\limits a_nz^n$ be an entire function on $\mathbb C$ with exponential type $\tau$, that is $\overline{\lim}_{r\to+\infty}\limits\frac{\ln(|f|_r)}r=\tau$ with $|f|_r=\max_{|z|\le r}\limits|f(z)|$.

Fact 1) The Borel-Laplace transfor of $f$ $F(w)=\sum_{n\ge0}\limits a_nn!w^{-(n+1)}$ converge for $|w|>\tau$. OK!

Fact 2) One has the relation $f(z)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma e^{zw}F(w)\mathrm dw$, for any simple closed path $\Gamma$ lying entirely in the holomorphy domain of $F$. I do not see the reason this eqality holds. For me, since $\Gamma$ is in the holomorphy domain of $F$, the function $e^{zw}F(w)$ has no pole inside $\Gamma$. So the integrale is $0$. Where is my mistake?

Fact 3) One has the equality $\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{f(n)}{z^{n+1}}=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma\frac{F(w)}{z-e^w}\mathrm dw$ for any $z$ outside the path $\Gamma'=\exp(\Gamma)$. That's surely a consequence of Cauchy formula, but I do not manage to obtain this equality.

Fact 4) Let $g(z)=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{f(n)}{z^{n+1}}$. If $\tau<\pi$, then $f(z)=\int_{\Gamma'}e^{z\ln w}g(w)\mathrm dw$. Here, I am completely lost....

Thanks in advance for any help and answer that you could give me.